# Get session object from one controller method to another

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can I know how can I get the session object which I have set in one controller method to another controller method.

Code:

```
    public ResponseEntity<String> generateId(@RequestBody IdCreationVO idCreationVO, HttpServletRequest request) throws CareBusinessServiceException {
    log.info("In Controller Method: generateId : "+idCreationVO.toString());

    if(null !=idCreationVO && null == idCreationVO.getIsSupressCommunication()) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute(AmhiConstants.COMMUNICATION_SUPPRESSED, idCreationVO.getIsSupressCommunication());
        log.info("session object communication: "+ idCreationVO.getIsSupressCommunication());
    }

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    return new ResponseEntity(idCreationService.generateId(idCreationVO), headers,
            HttpStatus.OK);
}


public ResponseEntity<String> updateAuthorizationDetails(@RequestBody AuthorizationVO authorizationVO, HttpServletRequest request) throws CareBusinessServiceException {
    String communicationSuppressed = null;
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    String authNbrResponse  = idCreationService.updateAuthorizationDetails(authorizationVO);
    if(null != request.getSession()) {
     communicationSuppressed = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(AmhiConstants.COMMUNICATION_SUPPRESSED);
        log.info("communicationSuppressed value: "+ communicationSuppressed);
    }
    /** This method is get triggered from controller as the communication registered functionality get excecuted before updateAuthorizationDetails ends **/
    if (null != authNbrResponse && communicationSuppressed.equals(AmhiConstants.CONSTANT_Y)) {
        String[] authorizationNumber = authNbrResponse.split(":");
        if (authorizationNumber.length > 1) {
            if (authorizationNumber[1].equalsIgnoreCase(AmhiConstants.STATUS_SUCCESS)) {
                idCreationService.triggercommunicationAfterAuthorizationRegistered(authorizationNumber[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity(authNbrResponse, headers,
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

As per requirement I need the value which been sent in generateId method to be get used in updateAuthorizationDetails method.

Can I know the above code implementation works fine in user session?

Answer (score 0):

`session.setAttribute` and  `session.getAttribute` methods should work.

But the problem seems to be in the if condition:

```
if(null !=idCreationVO && null == idCreationVO.getIsSupressCommunication()) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute(AmhiConstants.COMMUNICATION_SUPPRESSED, idCreationVO.getIsSupressCommunication());
        log.info("session object communication: "+ idCreationVO.getIsSupressCommunication());
    }
```

It checks whether `idCreationVO.getIsSupressCommunication()` is `null` and then sets it to the session. In other words, it only sets the variable to the session when it is `null`.

I guess you mean:

```
if(null !=idCreationVO && null != idCreationVO.getIsSupressCommunication()) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute(AmhiConstants.COMMUNICATION_SUPPRESSED, idCreationVO.getIsSupressCommunication());
        log.info("session object communication: "+ idCreationVO.getIsSupressCommunication());
    }
```

Comment: whether session object get maintained based on the user login. Just for confirmation as UI is developed by separate team

Comment: Yes, but if you login with the same user from distinct browsers they won´t share the same `HttpSession`.  Each time you login it creates a distinct session.